# Flutter: make some calculation with firestore data

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I try to make a bet app and unfortunately can not calculate the correct score of the user. The underlying data is from a football database in json format, which I present in the app with the usertips in a card.
Here is a screenshot of my firestore data:

[image: screenshot firestore]

here a snippet Listview.builder:

```js
 Widget _buildBody() {
    return new Expanded(
        child: new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i) {
```

the presentation and bet of the user work well, here is a screenshot:

[image]

I integrated the user bets via a streambuilder.
Unfortunately, the automatic scoring does not work, the user should get one point per correct tip.

Does anyone have a good suggestion on how to implement the calculation?